# Euclidean norm bound

Tags: normed-spaces

Consider the variable $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, where each element $i$ is restricted to live in the interval $\underline{x}_i\le x_i \le \bar{x}_i$. Now consider the norm $\|x\|_2$. Why can't I write the following?
$$\|x\|_2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2\right)^{1/2}\le \left(\sum_{i=1}^n|\bar{x}_i|^2\right)^{1/2} = \|\bar{x}\|_2$$
where $\bar{x} = (\bar{x}_1,\ldots,\bar{x}_n)$. The inequality should follow directly from the fact that $x_i\le\bar{x}_i$ for all $i$, but the example $\underline{x}_i = -5\,,\forall i$, $\bar{x}_i=1\,,\forall i$, and $x = (-4,-4,-4)$ violates the above inequality since $\|\underline{x}\|_2 = \sqrt{75}$, $\|\bar{x}\|_2 = \sqrt{3}$ and $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{48}$. What's going on? What is the correct upper bound on $\|x\|_2$? What about for the case where we are trying to find a bound on $\|x+a\|_2$ where $a$ is some fixed vector?

Comment: the function $f(x) = |x|^2$ is only increasing over positive values of $x$.

Comment: Note that $-1<0$ but $(-1)^2=1>0=0^2$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you. Is the bound $\|x\|\le \|\underline{x}\| + \|\bar{x}\|$? Is there a tighter bound?

Comment: There is no reason for this bound to hold unless the entries of $\underline{x}$ and $\overline{x}$ are non-negative.